# Teaching vs Training

Tags: meaning, verbs

I think **training** mostly refers to the physical related process as it used frequently in sport context, however I found instances in which verb **teaching** is used in such situations. Am I right? and is there any substantial difference between them.

**Merriam-Webster** says:

> **Train** : to teach (someone) the skills needed to do something (such as a job), to give instruction to (someone)

and

> **Teach** : to cause or help (a person or animal) to learn how to do something by giving lessons, showing how it is done, etc.

Based on the M-W definition, the movie "*How to train your dragon*" could be retitled as "*How to **teach** your dragon*".

As another example, in the following sentence:

> Select the methods for implementation. - Study how to implement a selected machine learning method to **teach soccer player** an individual skill.

I think it would be better to use `train` instead of `teach`.

And one more example in a different direction :

> ...research shows a connection between the missing penmanship discipline and the failure to **train the brain** for impulse control.

Any idea on how to use them properly?

Comment: ***Taining focuses on skill*** ; the definitions imply a narrower focus than teaching and possibly a shorter timeframe. We might associate training with the notion of exercises that we repeat until we "get" the skills we are trying to acquire - until they become almost second nature. ***The definitions for teaching,*** in contrast, imply deeper knowledge and a longer timeframe. We often hear the term "lifelong learning," but I can't recall ever hearing about "lifelong training."

***Teaching versus training***: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3810.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of the second object differs:

- You teach a soccer player an individual skill.
- You train a soccer player ***in*** a skill. (You can't train someone a skill)

---

If you don't use the second object, both sentences are valid, but mean slightly different things. To train someone is more involved than to teach someone.

From vocabulary.com:

**[teach](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/teach)**:

> To teach is to transfer ideas or skills to another person. As an old saying goes, "Give someone a fish, they eat for a day, teach someone to fish and they eat for a lifetime." I hope they like seafood.
>
> The Old English word tǣcan, which became the Middle English techen, meant "to show or point out." But the Old English also had another word for teach — læran — which eventually became the modern "learn," with the current meaning of receiving knowledge rather than giving it.

**[train](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/train)**:

> To train means to teach a skill. If you train your cat to use the toilet, your family will be amazed.
>
> You can train animals to perform in a circus or roll over, and you can train people to do things like program computers or use an espresso machine. When you instruct someone how to do a task, you train him or her.

Comment: There can be teaching in training but not vice versa?

Comment: @Mrstupid:: If there's training in teaching, they'd just call it training.

Comment: that makes sense.

Comment: In fact they mostly call it 'teacher training'. Presumably there is 'trainer training' as well, but I have not come across it.

Answer (score 3):

I often find myself in a position where I am required to ***train*** a new employee. (I have several different fields of expertise, so this method is pretty universal.)

I begin by ***teaching***: *Exposing* the person to various products/tools/equipment that will be utilized, and *imparting* my knowledge of them. (I will *demonstrate*.)

The ***training*** part, is *guiding* the person in their attempts to become proficient with the aspects I have presented to them. (Now, they must get their own hands dirty.)

Answer (score 0):

*Teaching* is an act by which you make people understand new things. You can *teach* a kid the high school math. By *teaching* you introduce people to things. You convey what you actually know to the other.

By *Training*, you *make people capable* of doing what you can do and people can't/struggled to an extent to do initially.

*Teaching* may be perceived as, something you *explain* to the other person. And by *Training* you train or make people do it themselves

Answer (score -1):

You can teach a fact or a skill, but you cannot train one. Likewise, you can attend training, but you can't attend teaching.